# Trying to create a tabbed application in swift with tableviewcells that launch Links in SafariViewController

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I am extremely new, followed the getting started guide for swift on Apples site.

I am trying to create a Tabbed App, each tab being a price range of gifts, and each gift being a tableviewcell with its own image and label. I also want to be able to click on the tableviewcell to open SFSafariViewController with a link directly to that gift online.

So far I have been able to create the tabbed application, create the table views and cells for each tab as static lists, setup the tableviewcells with images and labels, but I am stumped as to how to make it so that clicking on each tableviewcell opens a URL in the app.

Just looking to see if there’s anyone who has done something similar or could help me out. So far I have done almost all of it in storyboard, and if a storyboard solution exists that would be amazing. If not, any help at all would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is make use of `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. This is a `UITableViewDelegate` method that is called anytime a cell is clicked. What you could do is check the `IndexPath.row` of the cell selected, and create an instance of `SFSafariViewController` that opens the corresponding `URL`:

```swift
import SafariServices
import UIKit

class YourViewController: UITableViewController {

    ...

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        var controller: SFSafariViewController!
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            let url = URL(string: "www.website1.com")!
            controller = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
        case 1:
            let url = URL(string: "www.website2.com")!
            controller = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
        default:
            break
        }
        present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably exactly what I’m looking for! Unfortunately I walked away from the computer in frustration so I’ll try again in a couple of hours and let you know if it worked. Either way thank you for the answer, super fast!

Comment: I'm sure it will work. Are your cells dynamic, or will they always be in the same order. There will be a little more work to be done if they are dynamic, but if they are static, it should be as simple as referencing the `indexPath.row` of the selected cell. Read up a bit more on `UITableViewDelegate` here: `https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate`

Comment: They are all static, and will always be displayed in the same order

Comment: I must be doing something very wrong as I was not able to get this working... here is what my code looks like in the tableviewcontroller:
https://imgur.com/QJQchuY

Comment: Okay, update you switch statement to as I edited it in my answer. You need a `default` case in your switch. Also, have you subclassed your `UnderFiveTableViewController` as a `UITableViewDelegate` elsewhere?

Comment: No I have not, I created everything in storyboard, then I created a new file called UnderFiveTableViewController

Comment: The issue is that you are subclassing `UITableViewController`, I was using an example where you subclass a `UIViewController`. Since `UITableViewController` already conforms to `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`, there is no need to redeclare this.